# Make pristine Angular form control dirty

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

There is a reactive form in Angular 4, and some control is supposed to be set programmatically at some point.

```
this.form = formBuilder.group({
  foo: ''
});
...
this.form.controls.foo.setValue('foo');
```

How can control pristine/dirty state be affected? Currently I'm using both `form` and `foo` pristine states, something like:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input [formControl]="form.controls.foo">
</form>

<p *ngIf="form.controls.foo.pristine">
  {{ form.controls.foo.errors | json }}
</p>

<button [disabled]="form.pristine">Submit</button>
```

If pristine/dirty is supposed to designate only human interaction and can't be changed programmatically, what solution would be preferable here?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Each instance of `formControl` has `markAsDirty()` and `markAsPristine()` methods (inherited from AbstractControl), so, you should be able to run

```
this.form.controls.foo.markAsPristine()
```

or better, using reactive forms API:

```
this.form.get('foo').markAsPristine()
```

or even

```
this.form.markAsPristine()
```

the same may be done with `markAsDirty()` method

Comment: markAsDirty worked like a charm!

Comment: Nice, basically pristine and dirty are opposite to each other, so you have pristine and non-pristine (dirty), or you could see it the other way around, like non-dirty (pristine) and dirty.