# How to set formgroup data from angular

Tags: html, angular, formgroups

I have a formgroup like below:

```
 this.myform = this.fb.group({
      mydata: ''
    });
```

I was able to set the data with formgroup setValue but in rendering the values in HTML, the option was not selected.
This is the HTML:

```
   <div *ngFor="let item of (items$ | async); index as i; first as first">
        <input type="radio" id="{{item.itemId}}" name="test" value="{{item.itemId}}"  [formControl]="myform.controls.mydata" 
    selected = "(items$ | async).length ===1">
</div>
```

This doesnot select the first input label in HTML but in typescript the form is valid .

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Just add `selected` on your `formControlName="mydata"`. Everytime you istance your form is set to valid just look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508982/make-pristine-angular-form-control-dirty

Comment: is it possible to do this dynamically like selected = "{{item.length >1}}" It doesnot really work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [setValue()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setvalue) method to set a new value for an individual control. The `setValue()` method strictly adheres to the structure of the form group and replaces the entire value for the control.

```
this.myform.setValue({ mydata: 'yourData' });
```

Comment: This doesnot update the HTML. I cannot see the radio button beign selected

Answer (score 1):

use the `patchValue` to set the value for the whole form

```
 this.myform .patchValue({ mydata: 'yourData' });
```